# Google Map Javascript heatmap with large latitude and longitude pairs

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary

I have around 2500 latitude and longitude pairs and I am trying to create heatmap with it using Google Map Javascript API. But it seems working only for around 1000 points or so.
Is there any limitation on the no of pairs?
Please clarify.

-Mani